# Проверка на существование куки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как проверить записанны ли куки в браузере, в данном коде я сначала записал куки в браузер, далее мне нужно вывести сообщение что куки записаны, но почему то не получается.

```
                      $('.vspl-reset').click(function(){
                        var cookie = "reset=block2";
                        document.cookie = cookie;
                      })
                      if (cookie!=null) {
                        alert('куки записаны');
                      }
```

Comment: мне просто интерестно, на код в том виде, в котором вы скинули в вопрос, вам лично смотреть не больно ?

Comment: Я код закинул не для оценки  красоты, а для оценки функционала, и мой вопрос был в том почему не работает данный код!

Answer (score 0):

Так переменная куки доступна только в теле функции

```
$('.vspl-reset').click(function(){
    var cookie = "reset=block2"; //cookie - локальная переменная, которая видна только в данной функции
    document.cookie = cookie;
})
if (cookie!=null) { //переменной "cookie" не существует. Нужно либо перенести проверку в функцию выше, либо объявить "cookie" до начала функции, либо проверять сами куки "document.cookie"
    alert('куки записаны');
}
```

Comment: еще стоит упомянуть что "сетится" данная "кука" в ивенте, а проверяется сразу после того как повесили хендлер...